# How to add 1 image i top of multiple image on css

Tags: html, css, image

Hello I wanted to know if please can some one could help me to add one image called or loaded from css to a multiple images on html.

EXAMPLE:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check I code something for you let me know if it work for you/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work for you

```css
.image-wrap {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.image-wrap:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url(https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png/google-logo-png-suite-everything-you-need-know-about-google-newest-0.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/450" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks works good but if i use image with link dosent work target blank.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one thing you could do.

Make sure the image sample ( has no background color ). then give it the same size and postion as the image with the background. when thats done give the image sample and z-index of 1. which will push it above the other picture.

```
    .image1
    {
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .imge2
    {
      position:absolute;
      top: 25px;
      left: 45%;
      z-index: 2;
      width: 300px;
      margin: auto;
    }
```

hope this is the solution to your answer

Comment: or just edit the picture in paint, photoshop. and add them together as one image.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are need something like this.**

```css
    .fi
    {
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .fi2
    {
      position:absolute;
      top: 25px;
      left: 45%;
      z-index: 2;
      width: 300px;
      margin: auto;
     
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


<div>
  <img src="https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2021/07/1627377451_nature-1600x900.jpg" class="fi" >
</div>
  <img src="https://media.newyorker.com/photos/5a95a5b13d9089123c9fdb7e/2:2/w_3289,h_3289,c_limit/Petrusich-Dont-Mess-with-the-Birds.jpg" class="fi2">
</body>
</html>
```

**Let me know if this helps you**